# Rails/Mongoid: How to change a mongoid model name? Data should not loose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongoid model in my rails application as follows

```rb
class Groups::Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
end
```

I wanted to change this model as follows

```rb
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
end
```

If I simply change the model name, I will be loosing the data since the mongodb tablename will be different. How will I do without loosing the data. Also I wish my mongodb collection/table name should update to posts from groups_posts.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about how Mongoid handles nested classes but it should be something like `store_in collection: 'group_posts'`. If you want to change the name of the collection you could do it via [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/).

Answer (score 0):

Just to echo max's comment in a little bit more detail:

The `store_in` macro can be used to change the persistence information at the class level:

> "The collection for the model’s documents can be changed at the class level if you would like them persisted elsewhere. You can also change the database and client the model gets persisted in from the defaults." [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/7.4/reference/persistence-configuration/index.html?_ga=2.141769458.1713202830.1658432490-1768080963.1655825865#document-storage)

```rb
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: "citizens", database: "other", client: "analytics"
end
```